# typescript - convert string to number

Tags: javascript, typescript, casting

```
totalbalancetemp = (Number(this.balance)) + (Number(this.pastAmount));
```

My `totalbalancetemp` is returning undefined whereas `this.balance` is equal to 34 and `this.pastAmount` is equal to 23.

I have this in controller and displaying `totalbalancetemp` using exp in html

Comment: if **totalbalancetemp** is a property of the component. then shouldn't you call it by **this.totalbalancetemp**

Answer (score 2):

Supply the proper type.

```
let totalbalancetemp:number = balance + pastAmount
```

This will throw an error, because you are now guaranteeing that `totalbalancetemp` will be a `number`.

> The type String is not assignable to type 'number'

Try the following:

```js
let balance:string = '34',
    pastAmount:string = '23',
    totalbalancetemp:number = 0

totalbalancetemp = Number(balance) + Number(pastAmount)

alert(totalbalancetemp)
```

Comment: It is still giving me 0 as totalbalancetemp and not adding these values actually balance is like from json like this.payment.total and this.payment.pastAmount

Answer (score 2):

```
totalbalancetemp = (Number(this.balance)) + (Number(this.pastAmount));
```

please try this it should work

```
totalbalancetemp:number = (+this.balance) + (+this.pastAmount);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var totalbalancetemp = null; this.balance = 34; this.pastAmount = 23; 

totalbalancetemp = (Number(this.balance)) + (Number(this.pastAmount));

alert(totalbalancetemp);
```

-->totalbalancetemp - Define Variable (or) any type

Answer (score 0):

totalbalancetemp should be replaced by this.totalbalancetemp if it's part of the angular 2 component

Answer (score 0):

Do a `+this.balance` in the .ts file or `this.balance*1` or `this.balance/1` on  in the template file.